# How to get previous URL with help of $window?

Tags: angularjs

I use $window service in my controller.

At some point I need to get previus URL.

Any idea how can I get previus URL whith help of $window service?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use : `document.referrer` to check the previous URL.

Or in your run function, you could listen to `$locationChangeStart` or `$locationChangeSuccess`

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
   console.log('start', evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl);
});

$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
   console.log('success', evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl);
});
```

Comment: I tryed to use document.referrer but I get emplty string.

Comment: @Michael: You could also listen to $locationChangeStart or $locationChangeSuccess here...

Answer (score 0):

To get the last route you need to use one of the following events:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    //...
});
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',function(eventt, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    //...
});
```

The `$locationChangeStart` event is broadcasted before the URL changes, while the `$locationChangeSuccess` event is broadcasted after the URL has been changed.
For more info have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#events).

---

If you just want to go back to the previous route try this:

```
$window.history.back();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App.run(function($rootScope) {   
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, newUrl, oldUrl){   
      console.log('success', oldUrl.templateUrl); });    
});
```

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score -1):

To go back:
`$window.history.back();`

To get the URL as a string:
`var url = $document[0].referrer;`

Comment: I get error on this row $document[0].referrer; I make injection in my controller $document